# Stored Procedure: Error 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am receiving an error 1064 on the following stored procedure:

```
12 DELIMITER //
13 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_python_photo;
14 CREATE PROCEDURE add_python_photo(  IN fname VARCHAR,
15                                     IN fpath VARCHAR,
16                                     IN fdata LONGBLOB,
17                                     IN python INT,
18                                     IN is_preferred TINYINT,
19                                     OUT python_photo_id INT)
20 BEGIN
21     INSERT INTO python_photo (  file_name,
22                                 file_path,
23                                 file_data,
24                                 python_id,
25                                 preferred)
26                         VALUES (fname,
27                                 fpath,
28                                 fdata,
29                                 python,
30                                 is_preferred);
31 
32     SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO python_photo_id;
33 END//
34 DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
mysql> source stored_procedures/add-python-photo.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
                                                                    IN fpath VARCHAR,
                                                                    IN fdata LONGBLOB,
                                                                    IN python INT,
' at line 1
```

I'm uncertain as to what syntactic error MySQL is referring to. The list of *'IN'* parameters appears to be syntactically correct - yet, that appears to be the source of the error. It seems to fail while processing the *'IN python_id INT'* parameter.

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding the *DELIMITER* suggestion, below is another stored procedure - which executes correctly:

```
12 DELIMITER //
13 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_python_parent;
14 CREATE PROCEDURE add_python_parent( IN python_id INT,
15                                     IN mother_id INT,
16                                     IN father_id INT)
17 BEGIN
18     INSERT INTO python_parent (python_id, mother_id, father_id)
19         VALUES (python_id, mother_id, father_id);
20 END//
21 DELIMITER ;
```

Execution:

```
mysql> source stored_procedures/add-python-parent.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the not the syntax of the stored procedure but the `DELIMITER` statement.

There are two simple solutions

## SOLUTION #1

Change the `DELIMITER` after you drop the procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_python_photo;
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE add_python_photo(IN file_name VARCHAR(20),
                                  IN file_path VARCHAR(20),
                                  IN file_data LONGBLOB,
                                  IN python_id INT,
                                  IN preferred TINYINT,
                                  OUT python_photo_id INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO python_photo (  file_name,
                              file_path,
                              file_date,
                              python_id,
                              preferred)
                      VALUES (file_name,
                              file_path,
                              file_data,
                              python_id,
                              preferred);

  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO python_photo_id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

## SOLUTION #2

Use the DELIMITER `//` with the `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS`

```
DELIMITER //  
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_python_photo //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_python_photo(IN file_name VARCHAR(20),
                                  IN file_path VARCHAR(20),
                                  IN file_data LONGBLOB,
                                  IN python_id INT,
                                  IN preferred TINYINT,
                                  OUT python_photo_id INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO python_photo (  file_name,
                              file_path,
                              file_date,
                              python_id,
                              preferred)
                      VALUES (file_name,
                              file_path,
                              file_data,
                              python_id,
                              preferred);

  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO python_photo_id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

## SUGGESTION

You should change the variables so that they are not the exact same name as the DB Columns

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_python_photo(IN given_file_name VARCHAR(20),
                                  IN given_file_path VARCHAR(20),
                                  IN given_file_data LONGBLOB,
                                  IN given_python_id INT,
                                  IN given_preferred TINYINT,
                                  OUT python_photo_id INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO python_photo (  file_name,
                              file_path,
                              file_date,
                              python_id,
                              preferred)
                      VALUES (given_file_name,
                              given_file_path,
                              given_file_data,
                              given_python_id,
                              given_preferred);

  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO python_photo_id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

## UPDATE 2016-10-10 13:51 EDT

Turns out to be the use of `VARCHAR` in the list of Stored Proc variables. While Other RDBMS products will allow for `VARCHAR`, MySQL will not accept it. `VARCHAR` variables must be followed by a width definition such as `VARCHAR(20)` in MySQL's Stored Proc variable list. This was pointed out by @ypercube in the comments, so all kudos for him on this one today.

Comment: I've tried modifying the DELIMITER statement as suggested - to no avail. Note, I have more stored procedures in this project which utilize the exact same order of statements, with regards to the DELIMITER/DROP statements - with no issues. I've applied your suggestion with regards to the variable names though.

Comment: @Rolando shouldn't that `VARCHAR` be `VARCHAR(20)` or whatever?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ you are right. I think other DBMS products will accept `VARCHAR` only in Stored Proc definitions, but not MySQL. You nailed the problem, so you should write that answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Just edit this one. I'm on a phone

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ OK I'll do that.